# How to subset data based on dates using Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, subset

I have a large dataset of financial transactions for many users during one year and i want to take a subset of the data such that a user has performed at least 1 transaction during each month of the year.

```
Date                   UserID
06/1/2012  20:35:59    1
08/1/2012  20:35:59    1
12/1/2012  20:35:59    1
12/2/2012  20:35:59    1
04/3/2012  20:35:59    1
09/4/2012  20:35:59    1
02/5/2012  20:35:59    1
04/5/2012  20:35:59    1
06/5/2012  20:35:59    1
14/6/2012  20:35:59    1
29/7/2012  20:35:59    1
03/8/2012  20:35:59    1
25/9/2012  20:35:59    1
08/10/2012 20:35:59    1
28/11/2012 20:35:59    1
27/12/2012 20:35:59    1
20/1/2012  20:35:59    2
09/2/2012  20:35:59    2
04/3/2012  20:35:59    2
```

So given the above the output should only have transactions of user 1 who has had transactions in each month of the year i.e.

```
Date                   UserID
06/1/2012  20:35:59    1
08/1/2012  20:35:59    1
12/1/2012  20:35:59    1
12/2/2012  20:35:59    1
04/3/2012  20:35:59    1
09/4/2012  20:35:59    1
02/5/2012  20:35:59    1
04/5/2012  20:35:59    1
06/5/2012  20:35:59    1
14/6/2012  20:35:59    1
29/7/2012  20:35:59    1
03/8/2012  20:35:59    1
25/9/2012  20:35:59    1
08/10/2012 20:35:59    1
28/11/2012 20:35:59    1
27/12/2012 20:35:59    1
```

The format of my dates is `'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'`
I am using Pandas.

UPDATE: Also i would like to incorporate into the code a way to be able to easily change the subset of users such that the subset would include users who have transactions in 11 out of the 12 months, or 10 out of 12, etc...

Thanks!

Comment: May I check, the "Date" column is currently a string, is that right?

Comment: After reading the data i performed the following for loop
`df['Date'][i] = datetime.strptime(df['Date'][i], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')`

Comment: You should parse the strings with `pd.to_datetime` (no loop needed): ``df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')`` (BTW this format you give seems not to correspond with the example data you show)

Comment: The original format of the dates is `'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'`